# Convert 8 bytes to double value

Tags: c++, arrays, double, converters

I read from a socket some hex data. The specification for this protocol tells me that the following 8 bytes represent a double Value.

So I have for example 8 byte like:

```
0x3F 0xD1 0x9B 0x94 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

(This value is saved in a char array so `Array[0] = 0x3F`, `Array[1] = 0xD1è...)

The represented double value is: 0.275120913982

How can I convert these 8 bytes to this double value?

I tried a lot of different things, but nothing works really. So I have no idea how I can manipulate it to a double.

Comment: Have you checked whether you need to perform a big-endian to little-endian conversion?

Comment: *"I tried a lot of different things, but nothing works really. So I have no idea how I can manipulate it to a double."* - it's kind of expected on SO that you show us what you've tried and actually explain what happened and how it didn't work, and what you don't understand about why.  Anyway, it's easy: `double d; memcpy(&d, &a[0], sizeof d);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use union, this works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    union { char b[8]; double d; };
    b[7] = 0x3F;
    b[6] = 0xD1;
    b[5] = 0x9B;
    b[4] = 0x94;
    b[3] = 0xC0;
    b[2] = 0x00;
    b[1] = 0x00;
    b[0] = 0x00;

    cout << "Double: " << d << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please note reverse order of bytes. It depends on endianness and can differ on your machine. Anyway it outputs:

```
Double: 0.275121
```

Comment: the usual qualifier about type-punning applies here since he's specified a C++ tag.